# After running setInterval see changes in database

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval

I have JavaScript function that runs every 4 seconds with setInterval. After executing for the first time this function calls an ajax, and changes column value in database. How can I see that this value has been changed in database, and if this value has changed, how to stop setInterval function running again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Capture the return value of `setInterval` in a variable
2. Have the HTTP server indicate in the response to the Ajax request if the value has changed
3. In the callback for the Ajax function test to see if the response says the value has changed and, if it has, call `clearInterval(that_return_value);`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to fetch the current values from the database and compare with the new values. Or, if your script is the only one ever making changes to the database (and the data is not too big to fit in memory), you could cache the values in memory to do the check.